# Get exit status of Android Monkey tool in Jenkins pipline

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration, monkey

I'm running test on an Android device using the monkey tool. The problem is the Jenkins pipeline passes as SUCCESS even when monkey crashes the app. Is there a way to get the exit code from sh or the monkey tool and mark the stage as a FAILURE?

```
stage('monkeytest'){
    node('android'){
        git credentialsId: '731f2b68-2c6d-', url: 'https://mygitrepo.git', branch: 'master'
        sh './gradlew installDebug'
        sh '/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb shell monkey -p com.my.package -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 10000'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sh` with returnStatus

```
result = sh('/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb shell monkey -p com.my.package -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 10000', returnStatus : true)
if (result != 0) {
    // handle errors
}
```